# Can anyone help me convert this vbscript to vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

```
Function Main()
  DTSGlobalVariables("bolFirstRecord").Value = True
  Main = DTSTaskExecResult_Success
End Function
```

Comment: You have not provided enough details for this to be converted. What is `DTSGlobalVariables`? Where does `DTSTaskExecResult_Success` come from and how is it populated? What return type is expected from `Main`?

Comment: Data Transformation Services (Sql Server 2000), those are probably global variables provided by the DTS VBScript engine, the question needs more background regarding the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

As Oded pointed out there is quite some information missing to advise you on this matter, but I think you need something like this:

```
Public Class MyForm1
  Private bolFirstRecord As Boolean

  Public Property FirstRecord() As Boolean
    Get
        Return bolFirstRecord
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        bolFirstRecord = value
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Function Main() As Boolean
     Try
        Me.FirstRecord = True
        Return True
     Catch ex as Exception
        Return False
     End Try
  End Function

End Class
```